# Kill all sleep processes

Tags: linux, bash

How do I kill all sleep processes that are running? I realize that I can either use the kill command to kill each process via its PID, or I can use pkill to kill the sleep command by name. I'm trying to figure out how I would do this, any help would be appreciated. I used

```
man pkill
```

to get some help but am still unsure.

Comment: You certainly do not want to do this

Answer (score 3):

If you really must do this dangerous action, use the [`killall`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/killall.1.html) command:

```
killall sleep
```

Comment: dangerous? How is it dangerous to kill a sleeping process?

Comment: Unless the process specifically handles `SIGTERM`, the process will be terminated immediately. This gives it no chance to perform any cleanup or write any data out to disk. Depending on what the process was doing when it was put to sleep, this could lead to data loss or corruption.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option for the pkill command that will kill all processes named the given pattern.

```
pkill -x [pattern] (or) pkill -exact [pattern]
```

These commands will kill all processes with the same name as [pattern]

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question. OP is asking specifically for sleeping processes, not how to kill a process in general